# How to stop running python programm?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

when testing my program using an exe file, I would like to be able to stop my program at any point. But unfortunately I don't know what the easiest method would be. can you please help Thanks so much.

Strg + break doesnt help!
And this doesnt work:

```
try:

    #session1 data
    keyboard = Controller()


    #----------------------------------------------Session1
        #1 Fenster
    pyautogui.click(107, 54, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.write(Dialog1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)

        #2 Fenster
    pyautogui.click(257, 33, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.click(258, 52, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.click(107, 54, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.write(Dialog2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1.5)

        #3 Fenster
    pyautogui.click(257, 33, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.click(258, 52, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.click(107, 54, 1, 1)
    pyautogui.write(Dialog3)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt: # alt + c
    Controller.exit()
    driver.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Why don't you debug your python script itself in a IDE and use breakpoints to pause execution at any point?

Comment: Thanks, no i am in tetsing now and my enduser wich tetsing the program has not that  possibility.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, you only have access to the python executable but not the code itself and you want to pause the execution of the executable file at any point in time when running it?

Comment: Yes correct, only exe file.

Comment: did you tried `process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'python file path/ filename'], shell=False)` when you want to kill the process just call `process.kill()`

Comment: Thanks for help. during executing exe file is CMD not open i cant typing there

Comment: Which operating system are you on? If windows, try `CTRL` + `S` while your executable file is running to pause it.

Comment: Windows. No ctrrl+s doesnt work

Comment: Is your executable file a console application?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 : Using Resource Monitor

- Run your executable file.
- Open Resouce Monitor application on Windows.
- Search for your task in the `CPU` table

[image]

- Right-click on task and click on `Suspend Process` option. This will pause the execution of your executable without closing it.
- If you want to resume your program, right-click again and choose `Resume Process` option.

## Method 2 : Using PsSuspend

- [Installation steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend)
- On command prompt type `PsSuspend absolute_path_to_your_executable_file` to pause your executable.
- On command prompt type `PsSuspend -r absolute_path_to_your_executable_file` to resume your executable.